# PHP search the parent key of a child value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, for example:

```
$array[ 'ex1' ] = array( 'link', '915', '716' );
$array[ 'am2' ] = array( 'image', '37', '685' );
$array[ 'ple' ] = array( 'video', '354', '675' );
```

If I call `$array[$ID][0]` I get `link`, great!

If I search for `link` I need to get the parent key, in this case `ex1`

This is my current solution:

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) { 
if( in_array( 'link', $value ) ) { $ID = $key; }
}
```

Is there a better way to set the array or search the parent key?

**EDIT**:

If I change the array format in this way:

```
$array[] = array( 'ex1', 'link', '915', '716' );
$array[] = array( 'am2', 'image', '37', '685' );
$array[] = array( 'ple', 'video', '354', '675' );
```

I guess it is more easy to get the $ID with `array_search( 'link', array_column( $array, 1, 0 ))` 
but then I cannot read! for example: `echo( $array[$ID][0] ) // should output link`

Which is the better solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `array_search` like this

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $ind = array_search("link",$array[$k])
    if ($ind) { $ID = $k; break; } 
}
```

and when you are out of this loop you could retrieve "link" with `$array[$ID][$ind]`.

The difference from you method here is that you don't get just a `true` or `false` like in `in_array`, but you also get the index of "link" with `array_search` inside your search block.

This, of course, wouldn't solve your problem when you search for a key which does not exist. Using your example,

```
$array[] = array( 'ex1', 'link', '915', '716' );
$array[] = array( 'am2', 'image', '37', '685' );
$array[] = array( 'ple', 'video', '354', '675' );
```

you'd get an error if you searched for 'alpha' using this method. The safe solution would be like

```
$ID = false
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $ind = array_search($needle,$array[$k])
    if ($ind) { $ID = $k; break; } 
}
if ($ID) {
    $element = $array[$ID][$ind]
} else {
    // The item searched for does NOT exist
}
```

This would search for the value in `$needle` in the haystack `$array` the way you want, I think.